# Convert OpenEXR to WebM Alpha Edges Grey

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, openexr

I apologise if this has been answered before. I have tried lots of options but can't seem to solve my issue.

I have a sequence of OpenEXR images that I want to merge into a WebM and include transparency. This I the basics of my ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i test%04d.exr exr.webm
```

The problem is the transparency looks dodgy on the edges. Here is an example of how it currently looks. The edge of the box should fade to white but the transparency shows a dirty grey.

[image: dodgy grey edges]

Here is an example exr file: [Test EXR File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4n45o88bxaucewm/test0027.exr?dl=0)

I've tried lots of things like

```
-vf premultiply=inplace=1
```

or

```
-pix_fmt yuva420p
```

but I can't seem to get it working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to sort this. It turns out I was very close. I needed to add:

```
 -vf unpremultiply=inplace=1
```

and also make sure I reload the generated webm in chrome.. you can't just refresh the page!